# SQLAlchemy - specifying options on model fields

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a flask application for the first time from scratch. I have written several applications using django.

I am following [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications) where few options are specified on model fields. e.g.

```
email    = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=False,
                                            unique=True) 
date_created  = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp(),
                                               onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
```

I want to find a list of all available options and their default behavior, like [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#field-options) does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking for constraints, I found column options [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column)

- [name](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.name)
- [type_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.type_)
- [*args](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.*args)
- [autoincrement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement)
- [default](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default)
- [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.doc)
- [key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.key)
- [index](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.index)
- [info](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.info)
- [nullable](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.nullable)
- [onupdate](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.onupdate)
- [primary_key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.primary_key)
- [server_default](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default)
- [server_onupdate](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_onupdate)
- [quote](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.quote)
- [unique](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.unique)
- [system](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.system)
- [comment](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.comment)